# How to sort RLMArray using property?

Tags: objective-c, realm, rlmarray

I'm trying to sort an RLMArray using its property but I am getting the error:

> This method may only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an
>   RLMRealm`

```
 RLMResults *rlmResults  =  [myLog.myRLMArray sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"orderNum" ascending:YES];
```

Here `myLog.myRLMArray` is a copy of data I get from the `RLMRealm`.

and `myLog` is declared as:

```
 RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(MyWidgetSet)
@interface MYLogObject : RLMObject
@property RLMArray< MyWidgetSet *>< MyWidgetSet > *myRLMArray;
@end
```

and my custom class is

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface MyWidgetSet : RLMObject
@property NSString *widgetName;
@property NSString *orderNum;
@end
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888339/rlmarray-retrieve-array-from-object) which was posted 2 years ago. I am hoping for an updated solution for this issue.I'm using Realm 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, the `sortedResultsUsingProperty` method can be used only for the object obtained by a query. You should save the object to Realm first. It is the best way to sort `RLMArray` for a performance.

Or if you'd like to sort `RLMArray` that has not been saved to Realm, you can use `NSArray`. So what you are doing is correct. The only thing is converting `RLMArray` to `NSArray` can be written in more simple. Just use `valueForKey:@"self"`, you do not need to iterate all elements.

```
NSArray *tempLog = [myLog.myRLMArray valueForKey:@"self"];
...
```

Comment: Good tip: -valueForKey:@"self"

Answer (score 1):

For now I am using NSArray to sort the data. I hope someone would come up with a better way of doing it directly using RLMArray

```
NSMutableArray *tempLog = [NSMutableArray array];
for (MyWidgetSet *tempSet in myLog.myRLMArray){
    [tempLog addObject:tempSet];
}
```

and sort using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`

```
 NSArray *tempWelLogCopy = [tempLog sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

        if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"orderNum"] integerValue] > [[obj2 valueForKey:@"orderNum"] integerValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"orderNum"] integerValue] < [[obj2 valueForKey:@"orderNum"] integerValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```

and add the sorted data back to RLMArray

```
    [myLog.myRLMArray removeAllObjects];
    [myLog.myRLMArray addObjects:tempWelLogCopy];
```