# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'This method may only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

Below is the code for getting Filtered list from Realm List but when i am passing predicate to list it is giving me crashing.

```
var services : List<ServiceBO>?
let predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isFavorite == yes", "")
            let li = .services?.filter(predicate)
```

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25896545/3901620

Answer (score -3):

You can try this.This code filters all the available objects of kind **ServiceBO** with evaluating your condition i.e **isFavorite == yes**

```
let filteredServices = realm.objects(ServiceBO).filter("isFavorite == yes")
```

Hope this helps you..!!

Comment: Actually i wants to query on List not from Realm Object

Comment: As Vishal noted, only Lists retrieved from Realms can be queried. However, you can convert unmanaged Lists to an Array and filter using Array's methods: `Array(services).filter { $0.isFavorite }`