# Swift - Error in when trying to convert a list of Realm objects (already saved to a realm) into results

Tags: ios, swift, realm, predicate, rlmarray

I am having an issue when trying to convert a `List<T>` into `Results<T>` using `RealmSwift`. I have a function that runs a set of results through multiple filters and returns the filtered results. One step in this process, however, requires some calculation and cannot be accomplished by applying an `NSPredicate` filter. I, thus, create a list and add the results to the list that meet the criteria. Since I need to return a set of results, I then apply a "TRUEPREDICATE" filter to the list. However, I end up getting a crash with the error message, "This method may only be called on `RLMArray` instances retrieved from an `RLMRealm`."

I have seen this problem occur in lists of objects that have not yet been added to a `Realm`, but these are the results of a previous query, and so have definitely already been saved to the database.

My code looks something like this:

```
    var results:Results<Object> = resultsOfSomeQuery

    let list = List<Object>()

    for result in results {

        if result.matchesSomeCriteria {

            list.append(result)

        }

    }

    results = list.filter("TRUEPREDICATE")
```

If anyone could clarify what is going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888339/rlmarray-retrieve-array-from-object/25896545#25896545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Since `Results` is auto-updating, it can only contain managed objects from `Realm`. This is why Realm's `filter` can also only be called on managed collections. You cannot use Realm's `filter` on a `List` that you created manually without persisting it in Realm.

If the filtering you need to do really cannot be done using `NSPredicate`s, then you need to resort to using non-updating collections.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I will try to figure out some other way to achieve the results I am looking for.